# Launching a ball with springs or with elastic bands

Tags: mechanical-engineering, springs

I’m a student and have to create a machine that can launch a small bowling ball to knock over some pins.

I was thinking that I could use elastic potential energy to launch the ball but I’m not sure if I should use springs or elastic bands.

The problem is that I don’t have a lot of space to work with because it can only be 0,5m x 0,5m x 0,5m. And for that reason I am leaning towards springs but I’m not entirely sure.

Thanks in advance, if you need more information about the project just ask.

Edit: For the project I have to launch a ball 12 meters away and knock over 5 bowling pins. I am not allowed to use pneumatics or explosives. The ball has to stay on the ground and the goal is to knock over the pins like in a bowling match so I need a way to aim my system to hit a different pin when I only hit a few of them, but I already have an idea for this. 
I thought about only using a ramp but when I calculated the speed it would have it would not be enough to consistently knock over bowling pins. Then I thought about adding springs or elastic bands or something like that to give it some extra speed.

Comment: Either spring or rubber band can work.  However, if we design this for you, you won’t get all the education value out of the assignment. I encourage you to experiment on your own.

Comment: A ramp might work...

Comment: look into bungee cords - easier to work with than rubber bands

Comment: Also consider pneumatics

Comment: A spring with a smooth tangental spline curve ramp?

Comment: Think about using gears and/or levers to match the "impedance" of the projectile with that of the energy storage system. search for "compound bow"

Comment: A compound bow setup with the bungee cords is exactly what I had envisaged :) But... We don't know what the goal is here - presumably maximum velocity exit isn't the target. Perhaps repeatability is, and a fine-tuneable aiming setup? Needs more details in the question to be able to give the best advice...

Comment: Range for the bowling ball? 10 feet or 100 feet? Is it allowed to roll on the ground? Or must it be airborne?